# How can I call non static methods from the main in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a non static method from the main method. all of these are in the same class, I know that if the method i am calling isnt static the program yields an error. How can i call the methods from the main without changing them to static?

```
public class BinSearch {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      createArray();

   }

   //creates an array
   public int[] createArray(){
   .....
   }
}
```

Comment: by learning java only. get a basic knowledge of class and you can solve your problem

Comment: i think you should read java basic more. then you wont get these doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate an object of the class in which that method belongs and you'll be able call that method. Like this:

```
public class BinSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BinSearch myObj = new BinSearch();
        int[] a = myObj.createArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of BinSearch

```
(new BinSearch()).createArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BinSearch {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      BinSearch bs = new BinSearch();
      bs.createArray();

   }

   //creates an array
   public int[] createArray(){
   .....
   }
}
```